# Modal UITableView Won't recognize first click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that I display modally. When the user clicks on any cell, I need to capture that choice and dismiss the view controller. The weird thing is that the first cell that is clicked is not recognized. When the user clicks on another cell, that is recognized and everything works as intended. Obviously, I need the first click to be the one that is recognized. What am i doing wrong?

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell clicked");

    // capture user selection and return to previous screen
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `DidDeSelect` instead of `DidSelect`.  Technically on first click you deselect nothing, but on second click (on a different cell) you do deselect something and your code fires.  I'm guessing that is your problem.

Comment: Why? Because I'm making stupid mistakes is what I do best of all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ;)

Comment: Ack! Thanks. It still took me about a minute to see the mistake!